# What algorithms should I use to create a skill-based matchmaking system?

Tags: algorithms

I would like to create a skill-based matchmaking system that can be used to match 2 players with a similar skill level. I intend to use it for Squash/Tennis/Golf ladder tournaments. Are there any pre-existing algorithms available that I might use to build such a system?

The input would be the matches won and/or lost. 
Thank you

Comment: This seems like more of a computer science question, maybe?

Comment: the line between math and computer science is very thin...

Comment: in places ... in others not so much.

Comment: What is the input? A set of players? **two** sets of players with equal size where you want to match players for each set? does each player have a single skill or several skills? each one of those questions is fundamental to answer your question efficiently. Please clarify. I would suggest you'll use graph theory notation, or maybe scheduling lingo

Comment: @TheHolyJoker please see my edit. The only input used is prior match related, so it can be total matches won, or the win/loss ratio

Comment: Your assumption at the end is not true in any of your examples. Indeed, any system with such a property is going to be just a single-knockout tournament.

Comment: lets say there are 25 to 50 players

Comment: @Maurice That makes no difference. In none of your examples is it the case that if A is better than B, then A will always beat B (a better definition would be "A beats B with probability > 0.5). Nor is it true that if A is better (by either definition) than B and B is better than C, then A must be better than C: you can have A reliably beating B, B reliably beating C, and C reliably beating A. No part of my comment depends on the number of players involved. Either you get rid of the conditions in your second paragraph, or you're just doing a single elimination tournament.

Comment: there i removed it. How about if A totally annihalates B with a 3-0 score, wouldn't that be a sign that A would also defeat C if B can't even win one round?

Comment: @Maurice No. It's entirely possible that, for example, A has a strategy that B can't beat, B has a strategy that C can't beat, and C has a strategy that A can't beat.

Comment: so do you know of a good algorithm for estimating outcome probabilities based on prior match results then?